# AssertionError in Tensorflow while_loop

Tags: python, while-loop, tensorflow

This may be super simple, but I'm not being able to find an answer. I'm trying to use a tensor inside the 'body' of the tf.while_loop. To keep it simple I'm just passing the (3,4) shaped tensor 'x' in it and, for the time being, doing nothing inside the 'body' function. But it seems the passing of this argument is causing some issues. The stack trace just tells 'AssertionError:'. Please help.
Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def cond(sequence_len, step, x):
    return tf.less(step,sequence_len)

def body(sequence_len, step, x):
    return (sequence_len, step+1)

step = tf.constant(0)
sequence_len  = tf.constant(10)
x = tf.zeros([3, 4], tf.int32)
res,step = tf.while_loop(cond,body,[sequence_len, step, x])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    step_eval = step.eval(session=sess)

print(step_eval)
```

The full stack trace is also pasted below.
[The image of the stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JpGJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

[tf.while_loop()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#while_loop)  You need to make sure that body() is a callable taking a list of tensors and returning a list of tensors of the **same length** and with the **same types** as the input. That's how While_loop works. Each returns are send back as input argument. That is, previous return are input parameter of next iteration.